# How to drop a database in previous installation MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed SQL Server, then I created a database named `TDT_SManage`. After that, I reinstalled SQL Server, recreate `TDT_SManage` database but I get an error:

> Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
> Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TDT_SManage.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>
> Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I tried to drop this database and it comes up with this message error

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot drop the database 'TDT_SManage', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Anyone who know how to fix it please help me? Thank you you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user database files from the original installation were not automatically deleted when you uninstalled SQL Server. You'll need to delete them manually to tidy up. Check these locations for the data and log files:

```
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TDT_SManage.mdf'
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\TDT_SManage_log.ldf'
```